# How to report issues with QGIS documentation?

Tags: qgis

I stumbled across a gotach while installing mod_fastcgi on MacOs 10.8 (mountain Lion) -- there is a bug in 10.8  in the apache build env which breaks the install instructions here: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial

The fix is to put a symlink

```
 sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.8.xctoolchain
```

as documented here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58186/how-to-compile-mod-wsgi-mod-fastcgi-etc-on-mountain-lion-by-fixing-apxserror

It would be good to get this noted in the docs...

Should I open standard bug report or is there a better way to report 'problems' with a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue is related to the MacOS version, you could contact William Kyngesburye directly. He is the maintainer of KyngChaos.

Reporting bugs in hub.qgis.org is nethertheless a good choice, helping others with similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it isn't an issue with the packaging but with the tutorial.  The instructions as given don't work with current versions of MacOS because of a bug apple introduced with there apache source configuration.

The tutorial has a MacOS specific section and that is what I would like to see updated.

Comment: Doh!  It's a wiki -- I can put the edits in myself! Silly me.  Just doing so and fixing a couple of minor mistakes in the as well.